# Data from WS 1 merged cells doesnt resize cell on WS 2 automatically with autosizing and wrap text set and doesn't resize back. Both WS's protected

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have merged columns and rows on worksheet 1, information is linked to another worksheet (2). Wrap text and autofit is assigned to cell of WS 2. Cell doesn't resize unless I take protection off and autofit cell again. Cell also doesn't resize back to normal when data is changed/deleted back on WS 1.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want the single cell in WS 2 to autofit without unprotecting sheet each time data is changed on WS 1's merged cells & rows.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, I believe you need to use a macro that will unprotect, autofit, re-protect your workbook on calculate. Something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Const pwd As String = "blugargleflabblebananahammocktwister"

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

Sheet1.Unprotect pwd

Sheet1.Cells.AutoFit

Sheet1.Protect pwd ', other parameters for your specific protection needs

End Sub
```

Obligatory note that it is not good practice to store your password as plain text in a VBA module.